# Generate Private Key with password from File

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have this command:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out host.key 1024
```

It asks me for a password, and I want to automate it! How I can make it read the password from a text file (host.pass) so it will not ask me, or have it ignore the password? Which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By omimtting `-des3` you won't be prompted for a passphrase (i.e. the key will not be encrypted).

Comment: thanks allot, what about if I want to use a password from a file?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the manpage of openssl and genrsa. According to these you can use the option `-passout file:host.pass`.